# Properties of regular semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

> > Let $a,b$ be elements of a regular semigroup $S$. Then $(a,b) \in \mathcal L$ iff there exist an inverse $a'$ of $a$ and $b'$ of $b$ such that $a' a = b'b$.

I have done the converse parts: if there exist an inverse $a'$ of $a$ and $b'$ of $b$ such that $a' a = b'b$ , then $(a,b) \in \mathcal L$.

Suppose $(a,b) \in \mathcal L$, so $a,b$ belongs the same $\mathcal D-$ class says $D$ and $a,b$ are regular, so every $\mathcal R$ class in $D$ contains an idempotent , it follows that $\mathcal R_b$ contains an idempotent says $e$.  how to proceed further .

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $(a,b) \in \mathcal{L}$. Then there exists an invese $a'$ of $a$ such that $a'a$ is an idempotent in $L_a = L_b$. You know that every $\mathcal{R}$ contains an idempotent says $e$, which implies that $\exists \ b' \in R_{a'a} \cap L_e$ such that $b'b=a'a$. The reason of $\exists \ b' \in R_{a'a} \cap L_e$ is explained as follows.

Suppose that $e \in R_b$. We get $(e, b) \in \mathcal{R}$, and $eb=b$, $bx=e$ for $x \in S^1$, where $S^1$ is obtained by adding $1$ to $S$ if necessary. Moreover, $(a'a,b) \in \mathcal{L}$ implies that $ba'a = b$, $yb = a'a$ for $y \in S^1$.

Take $b' = a'axe$. You could get $bb'b=b$, $b'bb'=b'$, $bb'=e$, $b'b=a'a$. So $b' \in  R_{a'a} \cap L_e$.

Comment: How $\exists b' \in \mathcal R_{a'a} \cap \mathcal L_e $ such that $b'b = a'a$

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: @ user120386  I have added the reason.

Comment: At last , I have doubt on $b'b= a'a$. Now $b'b = a'axeb = a'axb$, how to proceed.

Comment: @ user120386  $b'b = a'axb = (yb) x b = y(bx)b = y e b = y b = a'a$.

Comment: @ bing : Related to this problem if $(a,b) \in \mathcal H$ iff there exist inverse $a' , b'$ of $a$  and $b$ such that $a'a = b' b$ and $aa' = bb'$

Comment: $(a,b) \in \mathcal{R}$, we have $aa'=bb'$,  and you refer to Howie's book "Fundamentals of semigroup Theory ".

Comment: @ bing : in the case of $(a,b) \in \mathcal R$ , the inverse of $a$ and $b$ are different from $a'$ and $b'$ which are exist in the question .

Comment: In the book which you refer me Howie used the theorem 2.3.4 (2)  says if $b \in \mathcal D_a$ such that $\mathcal R_a \cap \mathcal L_b$ and $\mathcal R_b \cap \mathcal L_a$ contains an idempotent $e$ and $f$  respectively then $\mathcal H_b = \mathcal L_e \cap \mathcal L_f$   contains an inverse $a^*$ of $a$ such that  $a^* a = f$ and $aa^*= e$. Since $a'a \in \mathcal L_a = \mathcal L _b$ and $aa' \in \mathcal R_a = \mathcal R _b$ and both are idempotents. how to show that $a'a \in \mathcal R_a = \mathcal R_b$ and $aa' \in \mathcal L_a = \mathcal L_b$

Comment: I think we can  use this result if $e,f$ are idempotent in a semigroup $S$ , then for all $x \in \mathcal L_f \cap \mathcal R_e$ there exist $y \in \mathcal R_f \cap \mathcal L_e$ such that $xy = e $ and $yx = f$. Here $e = aa'$ and $f =aa'$, and $a'a \in \mathcal L_a  , aa'  \in \mathcal R_a$ , thus  $a \in  \mathcal L_{a'a} \cap \mathcal R_{aa'}$ so there exist $b'  \in  \mathcal R_{a'a} \cap \mathcal L_{aa'}$ such that $bb' = aa'$ and $b'b = a'a$

Comment: Yes.  It is shown in Proposition 2.4.1 in Howie' book.